# How do I make header.php use different css for different pages?

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

I register styles in `function.php` with

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'header' );
    wp_register_style( 'header', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'header' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_style_sheets' );
```

I'd like to use different header style sheet for the same header.php file used on another page. How do I do that?

In general, how do I use styles differentiated by template instead of using a global setting like the one above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a primary stylesheet and enqueue as normal.  Then, make a series of conditional statements using WP core functions - `is_home()`, `is_404()`, `is_page_template('template.php')` and so on.  In each of those conditionals, enqueue the stylesheet you want that overwrites your core stylesheet, using your primary (`style.css`) stylesheet as a dependency.

Untested code, but should work:

```
function my_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'header' );
    wp_register_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
    if (is_home()) { wp_enqueue_style('homestyle', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/homestyle.css', 'style'); }
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'my_styles');
```

Comment: Thank you. I also found these pages useful: [Function Reference/body class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class), [Contextually changing your theme’s stylesheet](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/07/27/contextually-changing-your-themes-stylesheet)